# Attempting to hide text in a .bmp with a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a .bat file that copies and combines two files into one, then deletes both files. The problem is I want to make it so that you enter the file locations (Via input from the user) instead of putting them in a specific folder with a specific name. Currently this is what I have:

```
@echo off
Echo Create two files inside of \secret\, one with text saved as Text.txt and the image as Image.bmp
pause
copy "C:\Users\Drew\Desktop\Secret\Image.bmp" + "C:\Users\Drew\Desktop\Secret\Text.txt" "C:\Users\Drew\Desktop\Secret\final.bmp"
del "C:\Users\Drew\Desktop\Secret\Text.txt" + "C:\Users\Drew\Desktop\Secret\Image.bmp"
echo Finished.
pause
stop
```

Comment: won't work this way.take a look at imagemagick

Comment: I know, this is the code to combine text and and an image with specific names in specific locations, and I wish to know how to make it so you are prompted to input text, which is then used for the location of the files.

Comment: If you combine a "text" file with an "image" file, you obtain a file of "texage" type that requires a _very special_ program to open it! **`:-)`**

Comment: It's a standard .txt file and a .bmp file. The BMP file can be opened in notepad and the contents of the text file are found at the end.

Comment: Question: Are you truly trying to hide private information in a BMP?  Like logins/passwords..  You may do better to get KeePass or similar tool.

Comment: No, it's purely something to work on the get better at creating batch files.

Comment: are you looking for `set /p`? See `set /?`

Comment: Deleting files won't work like this. Delete one at a time instead

Comment: @ThomasWeller, you *can* delete multiple files, but the `+` sign should be removed...

Comment: I recommend to use `copy /B` to tell the command the files are *binary*; otherwise, the BMP image portion might be impaired (see `copy /?` for details)...

Answer (score 1):

to ask the user for Input, use `set /p "variable=prompt text"`:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\Drew\Desktop\Secret"
dir /w *.txt 
set /p "text=Give me a Textfile: "
dir /w *.bmp
set /p "Image=Give me an Imagefile: "
set /p "Final=Give me a final Name: "
copy /b "%image%" + "%text%" "%final%"
del "%text%" 
del "%image%"
echo Finished.
pause
popd
rem stop is no cmd command
```

Reference: `set /?`, `dir /?`, `pushd /?`, `popd /?`